# How can I make this string from a 'textarea' to be on one single line?

Tags: php, html

I have tried and tried and tried now.

I have a mysql field (TEXT) which contains the value of a textarea.
That is, if the text is written EXACTLY like this:

```
   Hello. Hello.
   Hello.
   Hel
   lo.
```

Then thats how it will appear in the mysql field because Im using wordwrap and nl2br functions when inserting it there.

Now, I am creating a dynamic page, where the 'meta description content' is updated with the 'TEXT' content, BUT, in one long string without any breaks and new lines.

That said, I need to make text to be in one string.

I have used this:

```
  str_replace ("<br/>", "", $string);
```

This displays the text as one string, yes, but when viewing the source code of the page, you can see that the breaks are there, like this:

```
<meta name="description" content="
   Hello. Hello.
   Hello.
   Hel
   lo." />
```

I have also tried replacing the 
 with '\n' and others, without success...

How can I solve this irritating problem?

Let me know if you need more input, and I will update this Q.

Comment: Inserting HTML into the database is bad practice, if you are going to need to strip it out later. It would be better to use `nl2br()` when displaying, not inserting, the data.

Comment: yes, but still it have to be possible this way also...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace all groups of whitespace with a single space:

```
$output = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $input);
```

Comment: Nice.  I wonder if this is in the php core already in some manner?

Comment: http://codepad.org/EHlVDOMv

Here is that code in use solving that problem, on codepad.

Comment: This is working well to make single line from multiline. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing "\n" with "" instead.

Answer (score 1):

handy function:

```
function removeEmptyLines($s) {
return preg_replace("/(^[\r\n]*|[\r\n]+)[\s\t]*[\r\n]+/", "\n", $s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try to something like this str_replace("\n\r", "", $string);  I have found that sometimes the return character \r is hiding in there someplace.